# Implementing a more efficient queue

Tags: scala, data-structures, queue

I have two queue functions that transforms the queue with enqueue/dequeue, but leaves the original queue unchanged and creates a new queue with the elements removed or added.

```
type Queue[A] = List[A]

    def enqueue[A](e: A, queue: Queue[A]): Queue[A] = queue match {
    case Nil => List(e)
    case head :: tail => head :: enqueue(e, tail)
    } 

    def dequeue[A](queue: Queue[A]): Option[(A, Queue[A])] = queue match {
    case Nil => None()
    case head :: tail => Some((head, tail))
    }
```

However, this is an O(n) running time because it traverses the whole list.

I would like to create a more efficient way of enqueue/dequeue. I thought that creating two lists that would represent the queue. Like *front*, which would have the elements at the front, and *back* which can have the back elements in reverse. Then the functions enqueue/dequeue would call use them instead.

I'm looking to see if I am on the right track, or is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Yes, this is how standard scala.collection.immutable.Queue is working.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Having two lists allows you to represent a single queue backwards and forwards (giving you O(1) operations). The only thing you need to take into account with that implementation, is that when you dequeue and your back-to-front queue is empty, you need to check if you can dequeue from your front-to-back queue reversed and transform it to be your back-to-front queue!

Answer (score 1):

From the source of the standard library [Queue](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Queue.scala#L1):

`Queue` objects implement data structures that allow to:

- Insert and retrieve elements in a first-in-first-out (FIFO) manner.
- `Queue` is implemented as a pair of `List`s, one containing the ''in'' elements and the other the ''out'' elements.
- Elements are added to the ''in'' list and removed from the ''out'' list. When the ''out''list runs dry, the  queue is pivoted by replacing the ''out'' list by ''in.reverse'', and ''in'' by ''Nil''.
- Adding items to the queue always has cost `O(1)`. Removing items has cost `O(1)`, except in the case where a pivot is required, in which case, a cost of `O(n)` is incurred, where `n` is the number of elements in the queue.
- When this happens, `n` remove operations with `O(1)` cost are guaranteed. Removing an item is on average `O(1)`.